# Angular select option dynamically in *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ngselect, select-options

That's the scenario:
I have a data array of objects that contains different types of objects. It could be a text, a select or whatever. In the view I have an *ngFor to loop this data and it generates an object depending on the type. I could have 2 or 3 select, it depends on the json that i receive.
These select, can depend on the selection of an option from another one. So, the options of the second needs to change depending on the first selection. For instance:

First select that contains a list of jobs: I select option "developer"
Second select that contains a list of users: "It has to show me the users with that job selected"

I tried to create an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-qyt3fu

and here's the code:

```
import {Component, NgModule, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {NgSelectModule, NgOption} from '@ng-select/ng-select';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Angular ng-select <small class="text-muted"><a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select">Open in Github</a></small></h1>
        <div *ngFor="let item of data">

           <input *ngIf="item.type == 'text'" autocomplete="off" name="{{item.name}}" type="{{item.type}}" placeholder="{{item.label}}" [(ngModel)]="item.value">

          <br />
          <ng-select *ngIf="item.type == 'select'"
                    [items]="item.data"
                    bindLabel="label"
                    (change)="selectValue($event)"
                    placeholder="{{item.label}}"
                    [(ngModel)]="item.value">
          </ng-select>

        </div>

        <!--<p>
            Selected city: {{selectedCity | json}}
        </p>
        <p>
           Selected user: {{selectedUser | json}}
        </p>-->

        <hr />

        <div style="margin-top:300px"></div>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

    data = [
     {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "test",
        "label": "Test",
        "type": "text",
        "value": "Hello there"
      },{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "cities",
        "label": "Cities",
        "type": "select",
        "value": undefined,
        "data": [
          {id: 1, name: 'vilnius', label: 'Vilnius', reference: "job"},
          {id: 2, name: 'kaunas', label: 'Kaunas', reference: "job"},
          {id: 3, name: 'pavilnys', label: 'Pavilnys', reference: "job"},
          {id: 4, name: 'pabradė', label: 'Pabradė', reference: "job"},
          {id: 5, name: 'klaipėda', label: 'Klaipėda', reference: "job"}
        ]
      },{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "job",
        "label": "Job",
        "type": "select",
        "value": undefined,
        "reference": "cities",  
        "data": [
          {id: 0, name: 'developer', label: 'Developer', city: "Kaunas", item_reference: "kaunas", reference: "cities"},
          {id: 1, name: 'actor', label: 'Actor', city:"Pabradė", item_reference: "pabradė", reference: "cities"},
          {id: 2, name: 'lifeguard', label: 'Lifeguard', city:"Vilnius", item_reference: "vilnius", reference: "cities"},
          {id: 3, name: 'lawyer', label: 'Lawyer', city:"Pavilnys", item_reference: "pavilnys", reference: "cities"}
        ]
      },{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "users",
        "label": "Users",
        "type": "select",
        "value": undefined,
        "reference": "job",
        "data": [
          {id: 'anjmao', name: 'anjmao', label: 'Anjmao', job: "Actor", item_reference: "actor", reference: "job"},
          {id: 'varnas', name: 'tadeus_varnas', label: 'Tadeus Varnas', job: "Developer", item_reference: "developer", reference: "job"},
          {id: 'john', name: 'john', label: 'John', job: "Lawyer", item_reference: "lawyer", reference: "job"},
          {id: 'jason', name: 'jason', label: 'Jason', job: "Lawyer", item_reference: "lawyer", reference: "job"},
          {id: 'tom', name: 'tom', label: 'Tom', job: "Lifeguard", item_reference: "lifeguard", reference: "job"}
        ]
      }
    ] 

    selectedCity: any;
    selectedUser: any;
    comboHash: ISelectHash = {};

    constructor() {
      this.data.forEach(item => {
        this.comboHash[item.reference] = item.data;
      });
    }

    selectValue(event) {
      //console.log(event.reference);
      const newItems = this.data.filter(item => 
      {
        console.log(event.reference);
        item.name.includes(event.reference)
      });
      console.log(newItems);
      ///console.log(event, this.comboHash["job"]);
      //console.log(newItems);
    }

}
export interface ISelectHash {
    [name: string] : Array<any>;
}
```

In this case:

I select a city, the second select it filters for the jobs in that city, than I select the job and the third should filter the users with that job. Is that possibile? I also tried to filter with filter function using a hashmap but newItems is always null.

Comment: my friend, inside your selectValue(event), you can put in conditions to check if it matches the first selected option then you use it to filter the second select options

Comment: Assuming that the data of all select comes from an url. I can filter but when I fill the select with the result I can't know which one fill with the new data. And so i have the new data but in the first select only.

Comment: @End.Game , if possible ,  it's much easier if you serialize the data  into a more friendly format for your task. for example updating the data with keys/values of cities, jobs, users so you dont have to loop through everything every-time your UI updates. when user updates the city, you can get the city name and then only run the filter on your `jobs` array, and filter out jobs that dont match the city.
Then you can use that new filtered data and reconstruct a new data set for your ngFor that only includes jobs that match the city.

Comment: @pouyazad I think that this is the best way, thank you for the suggestion